# Thinclient Boot CD

Tags: edubuntu, ltsp

How can I create a bootable CD to run on an old PC accessing an LTSP server. I have found ample documentation on installing an LTSP server, but no reference on how to create a bootable CD. (PC emulating a thinclient).
My old PC does not support booting from LAN.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to download a floppy disk or usb disk image for PXE booting:

http://rom-o-matic.net/gpxe/gpxe-1.0.1/contrib/rom-o-matic/

This will allow you to take advantage of PXE/Net booting features.